# How to make Cortana understand pronounciation of made up words?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, cortana

I integrated my app in Cortana via VCD but the problem is my app name stored in the tag "AppName" is not a dictionary word. It is called "cybrick" and Cortana just does not understand it and pronounce it "cibrick" which is not acceptable. Is there a way to train Cortana how to pronounce words that are not in the dictionary? Maybe providing transcription or voice samples?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to train Cortana how to pronounce words that are not in the dictionary? Maybe providing transcription or voice samples?

No, this is not supported in Cortana now. Actually the **AppName** element is used to specify a **user-friendly** name for an app in a voice command.

In Voice Command Definition (VCD) elements and attributes v1.2, we can find following description:

> Specifies a user-friendly name for an app that a user can speak when giving a voice command. This is useful for apps with names that are long or are difficult to pronounce.
>
> Avoid using prefixes that conflict with other voice-enabled experiences.

[image]

So instead of training Cortana, I'd suggest you change the `AppName` element to a more user-friendly world or phrase so that users can easily interact with your app from Cortana.

For more info, please see [Support natural language voice commands in Cortana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voicecommands/support-natural-language-voice-commands-in-cortana).

Comment: Yes, I am already aware with all this. Unfortunately I can't change the name of my app, to fit Cortana's understandings. You should think of adding such recorded voice sample injection functionality in some form of audio file other than the VCD xml or support transcript of words. I should probably suggest it in UserVoice or another feedback platform.

Comment: @nmrlqa4 You are welcome to submit a request for this feature through UserVoice. And for Cortana issue, you can also use Windows Feedback App. ;) However, for now, I'm afraid using a user-friendly world or phrase as AppName is the only workaround. :(